# free( ptr ) error - invalid size

Tags: c

I have a c program that seems to be performing ok unless I call `free` on the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    gid_t *list;

    int num_groups = getgroups(0, NULL);

    list = malloc(num_groups * sizeof(list));

    if (getgroups(num_groups, list) != -1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < num_groups; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *list++);
        }
    }
    free(list); // free(): invalid size: 0x0000000002448040 ***
    return 0;
}
```

I've seen [lots of similar posts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=free%20%20invalid%20size%3a%20&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&oq=free%20%20invalid%20size%3a%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.14562j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that refer to **invalid next size**, but not for **invalid size**.

I'm a newbie when it comes to c - so I can't work out what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are changing `list` with your `*list++` and therefore the `free` is invalid. You need to `free` the original pointer obtained from `malloc`.

---

As dasblinkenlight notes, you're not allocating memory the right way. I think you were going for this idiom, but forgot the *:

```
list = malloc(num_groups * sizeof *list);
                                  ^
```

Comment: So should I create another pointer that points to `list` and increment the other pointer instead?

Comment: @Chris Sounds like a very reasonable plan :-)

Comment: You may want to mention that the OP is allocating an incorrect amount of memory: he allocates space for `num_groups` pointers to `gid_t`, rather than allocating `num_groups` of `gid_t`s.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - ok, now I'm really confused!

Comment: @Chris `sizeof(list)` yields the size of a pointer. `sizeof(*list)` yields the size of a `gid_t` - which is what you are looking for.

Comment: @cnicutar - makes sense, though I just checked on my dev machine and `sizeof(list) == 8` whereas `sizeof(*list) == 4` so I guess in this case it wasn't the cause of my issue, it was just reserving more memory than it actually needed?

Comment: @Chris It was an accident waiting to happen - perhaps moving to another platform things would have been the other way around. dasblinkenlight was right to point of the problem.